# SqlAlchemy/Python properly catch psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have the following code:

```
try: 
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
           
    newentry = MyTable( 
             some_data = "some data",
    )
    session.add(newentry)
    session.commit()
     
except psycopg2.OperationalError as oe:
    print("Not possible to connect to DB")
except psycopg2.ProgrammingError as dbex:
    print("Table does not exist")
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:    
    session.close()
```

How do I properly catch  `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable` ?

`psycopg2.ProgrammingError` seems not to work since the exception is printed at the third catch, and Tables get not created.
I tried also with `psycopg2.Error` with the same result.

Thanks for the help

Comment: How about `psycopg2.DatabaseError` ?

Comment: Here is the main docs https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html#exceptions

Comment: According to the docs: "exception psycopg2.ProgrammingError
Exception raised for programming errors, e.g. table not found or already exists, syntax error in the SQL statement, wrong number of parameters specified, etc. It is a subclass of DatabaseError". But I'll try with DatabaseError. Thanks

Comment: Others might also have the same issue as you did so I am wondering: did you build the session through sqlalchemy? The tag looks like you did but I can't tell from your code sample.

Comment: yes, session, engine and table models are built with sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found a way to do this. The trick is to first catch the initial error, then re-raise to catch the original error.

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

from psycopg2 import errors, errorcodes

url = "postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@host/database"

def get_version(url: str):
    
    try:
        return pd.read_sql("select version_num from alembic_version;", sa.create_engine(url)).loc[0, "version_num"]
    
    except sa.exc.ProgrammingError as e:
        
        try:
            raise e.orig
        
        except errors.lookup(errorcodes.UNDEFINED_TABLE):
            return None
        
print(get_version(url))
```

Comment: This works; alternatively, instead of re-raising, you can check `e.orig.pgcode == errorcodes.UNDEFINED_TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you built your session through sqlalchemy, the following will catch UndefinedTable errors:

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import ProgrammingError

# import other dependencies and create your session as before

try: 
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
       
    newentry = MyTable( 
             some_data = "some data",
    )
    session.add(newentry)
    session.commit()

except ProgrammingError as pe:
    print(f'Exception Caught: {pe}')
```